# Select player that does not have a specific score set

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to select all players that do not have a specific scoreboard objective value set. I have tried doing `testfor @a[score_hasJoined=]` and `testfor @a[score_hasJoined_min=]`, but it still won't work. The `hasJoined` objective is a `dummy` objective, and therefore users do not start with `0` when they join.

I want to set all players' score without the score to `0`. I have thought that there maybe is an objective that automatically starts at `0` but I couldn't find one.

Comment: I know this has come up before, but I can't find the question right now. I think it was a tangential issue for another problem.

Comment: Selecting someone without a score set is impossible, but we might be able to solve your actual problem. What exactly is it you are trying to achieve? Do you just want to select all players that have just joined the server for the first time? Or just joined in general? Or joined a minigame/team/...

Comment: Have you tried something like running `scoreboard players add @a hasJoined 0` (I think that's the correct syntax) on a 20Hz clock?  That should effect everyone, and won't actually change the value of the objective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you can't target someone without a score using a score selector.  So the solution, not surprisingly, is to give everyone a score.  You don't have to change anyone's score value either; instead, just "increment" everyone's score by 0, in your case, with the following command:

```
/scoreboard players add @a hasJoined 0
```

Better yet, throw that command in a command block that is triggered off a 20Hz clock, and you're guaranteed that everyone always has a score.

The way this works is that everyone that already has a score in the `hasJoined` objective won't have their score changed, but everyone else will have their `hasJoined` score set to 0.

Comment: Actually, I lied, you can target them, but I like this better.

Comment: How do you target them?

Comment: Actually, it looks like I was mistaken.  I had the syntax mixed up, and a test succeeded when it should have failed.

Comment: Thank you, this is sooooo helpful! Very creative solution. I didn't realize you could add 0 to everyone's score.